# Converting from base 16 to base 10 in reverse byte order

Tags: c#, .net, binary, network-programming

I am reading data from a network stream from hardware that starts with a fixed header followed by the length of expected data as a System.UInt16 whose first byte is 0x23 and the second byte is 0x00. The order of the bytes is supposed to be reversed according to the hardware documentation and the value I should expect to convert this ushort into is 35 which is 23 converted from base 16 to base 10.

How could I make this conversion programatically considering the reverse ordered bytes. I am using BinaryReader.ReadUInt16() at the moment.

**UPDATE:** Please note that I am not looking to convert to string using `System.Convert.ToString(value, base)` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for your?

```
byte a1 = 0x23;
byte a2 = 0x00;

ushort a12 = (ushort)(a1 << 8 | a2); //This what you receive
ushort a21 = (ushort)((a12 & 0xFF00) >> 8 | (a12 & 0xFF) << 8);
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand how you handle reversing the bytes but could you please explain how the values are being converted from hex to decimal? The masking logic seems simple but I am not clear on what it is doing.

Comment: @Raheel: Conversion is not necessary as you don't have a string. Your data is already in numeric format. The maskings are just to show the intension which bytes are needed. In fact the unnecessary parts are shifted or casted away. The "|" acts like "+" except that no overflow is handled. a21 = (ushort)(a12 >> 8 | a12 << 8) would also have worked or a21 = (ushort)((a12 >> 8) + (a12 << 8)). Additional parantheses are needed as + is "stronger" that "shift".